# command: ionic server Killed 9

Tags: macos, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic4

I am using mac system with Visual Studio Code. I have installed node version 20.11.1 and have installed cordova along with ionic. When i use the command `ionic serve` get a response as Killed 9 in Terminal of visual studio code. Appreciate any help.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask